# Is there a way to show both the Graphics and the Graphics 2 windows on an android tablet?

Tags: android, geogebra

Is there a way to show both the Graphics and the Graphics 2 windows on an android tablet? I can do that on my laptop by clicking the three dots menu on the upper right corner, but I cannot find a way to do it on my tablet.  Is it possible to do it?

I looked for the menu with this option everywhere but I cannot find it.